# Incrementing a string in a input box with Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am stuck. Can you help me?

I have an input box on a site, where the client number is entered. The number is in format NO0000 (contains both letters and numbers). I want the script to increment NO0000 with 1, depending on if the client number already exists.

For example, if I have NO000, i want the input to add an increment to the last number of the client no, so the output will be NO001.

I want to do this with Selenium webdriver on a page with an input box.

```
`#input client details
clientno = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_tbclient_no"]')
clientno.send_keys('NO000')
clientno = bytes(clientno, 'utf-8')
clientnoincr = bytes(clientno + 1)
clientnoincr = str(clientnoincr)`
```

When i do this, nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that `clientno` is the string `NO000`, then to increment it by 1 you can do

```
clientno = f'NO{int(clientno[2:])+1:03d}'
```

where `clientno[2:]` is `'000'` since `[2:]` skips the first two characters of `'NO000'`. The string `000` is then converted to a int, which is `0`. Then it sums 1 and convert it back to a string, putting leading zeros in such a way that the resulting string has three characters, i.e. `f'{4:03d}'` is `'004'` and `f'{19:03d}'` is `'019'`